Made a VS project using SDL2. It used to work but now I'm getting linker issues
At first it says that it couldn't open the files like "SDL.h not found", even though I included all the libraries and all that. So I switched it all over to x86 which fixed all of those problems but now I'm getting a linker issue saying that onecore.lib is not found. I read every tutorial I can find on how to adjust the project settings and include all the libraries. I can't find the onecore.lib file anywhere in the onecore folder of the Visual Studio program files.
Searched in every folder of 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\lib\onecore' and found no such file that VS is looking for. No idea what to do. I also included SDL2 path in the environment variables.

Not sure how you got in this situation but I found this documentation for OneCore.lib: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-umbrella-libraries

Read every tutorial but you are still setting environment variables? That's not how Visual Studio works. Whether its header files or libraries you use the project settings to tell Visual Studio where to find stuff. Switching to x86 probably only worked because you had the correct project settings for your x86 configuration but not for your x64 configuration. The correct fix is to edit the x64 configuration, not to switch to a different configuration.

Probably the best advice is to start again, since the settings for your current project seem to be all over the place. Create a new project and this time edit the project settings and be aware which configuration you are editing (x86 or x64, Debug or Release). There really are only three things you need to do. Tell VS where to find your header files, tell VS which libraries you want to link, tell VS where to find those libraries. And that's it, all these things are specified using project settings.

Restarted a 100 times already and re-did all the project settings using x64 and x86 as well as "all platforms" just in case. I reconfigured the project settings and linked all the libraries and included all the header files. I even redownloaded SDL2 and tried linking that one. And no, I'm not still setting environment variables, it was one of the first things I did and I just thought to mention it. I just didn't do it before because it used to work

I believe the easiest way to do this currently on msvc is to create a CMakeLists.txt for your application and use vcpkg to build sdl2. With that said I have used CMake at work since 2008 so I favor that approach.

@drescherjm Thank you but I figured it out. When adding the file paths from the SDL folder into the project properties in Visual Studio, I copied and pasted the path. This is fine because the paths are correct, but for some reason the file explorer uses the "" slash. I realized that in my other projects that work, Visual Studio uses the "/" slash. It's funny because every tutorial video shows people copy and paste from their file explorer, it only caused that issue for me. Nearly impossible to diagnose too because the paths were correct

Copy and pasting file paths to your include folders and libraries caused the file paths to have the "\" slash. Visual Studio expects the "/" slash. This subtlety caused all my issues and making that small change fixed everything. For some reason, people still suggest copy and pasting the file paths even though this issue can arise. As far as I can tell, I'm the only person that has run into this issue. Nearly every tutorial suggests copy and pasting file paths and none of them mention that the slash can cause issues. Very difficult to diagnose if you don't know because the file paths are correct and it's easy to assume that copying the path is good enough.
